# Is one way of importing python modules better

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I am writing python code with several interacting files in the same directory.

I am wondering if it is a preferred way. If I am in folder x importing file y as z my two options are:

```
from . import y as z
```

Or

```
Import x.y as z
```

I see the first option better as you are flexible in terms of not hardcoding the file name. Is this however more susceptible to bugs at all? I have heard this anecdotally that people have had more errors using the first option but no reasons why.

Answer (score 0):

#### Relative Imports

A relative import specifies the resource to be imported relative to the current location—that is, the location where the import statement is. There are two types of relative imports: implicit and explicit. Implicit relative imports have been deprecated in Python 3, so I won’t be covering them here.

#### Absolute Imports

An absolute import specifies the resource to be imported using its full path from the project’s root folder.

**Please** take a look at this article to know more about python imports : 
https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/